# If cell is blank or contains text

Tags: excel-formula

I want excel to return a value if a certain cell is not blank or contains the keyword "Interfaces" OTHERWISE return a blank value

I tried this but it didn't work

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!E40<>"","Interfaces"),Sheet1!E40,"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly check if the cell contains a value and if you have Excel 2007 or a later version you can use `ISBLANK()`. To generalize for any text you could also have `ISTEXT()` inside the `OR()`

try this

```
= IF( OR( ISBLANK(E40), E40 = "Interfaces"), E40, "")
```

and yes, you can have spaces in Excel formulas